# Add two arrays with the same length

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays,

`$arr_1 = array(01=>5, 02=>3, 03=>2);`
`$arr_2 = array(01=>3, 02=>4, 03=>0);`

what I want to achieve is to have a single array where the final form after adding the two arrays would be,

`$arr_3 = array(01=>8, 02=>7, 03=>2);`

I tried `array_merge` but it wasn't the solution.How would I attain the final form?

Comment: Have you tried using a foreach() loop to loop through the arrays and add the values?

Comment: what is wrong with array_merge?

Comment: @Stephan - array_merge will concatenate the arrays together; the OP wants to sum the values where the keys are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop should handle this:

```
$max = count($arr_1);
$arr_3 = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++){
    $arr_3[$i] = intval($arr_1[$i]) + intval($arr_2[$i]);
}
```

I'm sure there are many other ways to do this, but this is the first one that came to mind. You could also do a `foreach` loop:

```
$arr_3 = array();

foreach($arr_1 as $k => $v){
    $arr_3[$k] = intval($v) + intval($arr_2[$k]);
}
```

I'm just winging it here, the foreach is a little tricky to avoid the cartesian effects. Worth a shot though.

Answer (score 3):

Try [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). From the PHP Manual

> array_map() returns an array containing all the elements of arr1
>   after applying the callback function to each one. The number of
>   parameters that the callback function accepts should match the number
>   of arrays passed to the array_map()

```
$arr_1 = array(01=>5, 02=>3, 03=>2); 
$arr_2 = array(01=>3, 02=>4, 03=>0);

$arr_3 = array_map('add', $arr_1, $arr_2);

function add($ar1, $ar2){
    return $ar1+$ar2;
}

print_r($arr_3);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 7 [2] => 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you require adding elements matching by their key not by their position, you could try this:

```
$array1 = array(1=>5, 2=>3, 3=>2); 
$array2 = array(3=>3, 2=>4, 1=>0); //unsorted array

$keys_matched = array_intersect_key ( $array1 , $array2);
foreach ($keys_matched as $key => $value) {
   $result[$key] = $array1[$key] + $array2[$key];
}
print_r($result); //Displays: Array ( [1] => 5 [2] => 7 [3] => 5
```

Answer (score -1):

You would look through both arrays and add each value of each array together then add that result to another array.

```
 foreach($array1 as $val1) {
     foreach($array2 as $val2) {
    array_push($newArray, intval($val1)+ intval(val2));
} 
}
```

Comment: there will be 9 items in $newArray if size of $array1 is 3. nested foreach loop. . .